# How can I prevent Perl Moose Read-Only Attributes being set upon a call to new?

Tags: perl, attributes, new-operator, moose

I would like to simply declare a read only attribute in Moose that cannot be initialized in a call to new.  So after declaring the following:

```
package SOD::KuuAnalyze::ProdId;

use Moose;

has 'users' => (isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]', is => "ro");

1;
```

I do not want the following to work:

```
my $prodid = SOD::KuuAnalyze::ProdId->new(users => ["one", "two"]);
```

Comment: users has no default, how does it ever get set?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `init_arg` attribute configuration (see "Constructor parameters" in [Moose::Manual::Attributes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Manual::Attributes#Constructor_parameters_(init_arg))):

```
package SOD::KuuAnalyze::ProdId;
use Moose;

has 'users' => (
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]', is => "ro",
    init_arg => undef,    # do not allow in constructor
);
1;
```

Comment: This works nicely, thank you.  However it fails silently.  Is there a way to get it to throw an error whilst attempting ProdId->new(users =>  ['one','two'])?

Comment: If you use MooseX::StrictConstructor, module construction will fail if any invalid or disallowed arguments are passed to the constructor. I use it in almost all my Moose classes (for the rest, I use MooseX::SlurpyConstructor which grabs all arguments that aren't used by attributes).

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
package SOD::KuuAnalyze::ProdId;

use Moose;

has 'users' => ( 
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]', 
    is => 'ro', 
    init_arg => undef, 
    default => sub { [ 'one', 'two' ] }, 
);
```

Setting the `init_arg` to `undef` seems to be necessary to disallow setting the attribute from the constructor.